# invalid channel for service notification: Notification

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

My code works exactly fine as long as I use the Android Emulator to test it, but once I build it and try to use it on my mobile phone I get the following error:

```
    An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=channel_01 pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)

StackTrace:
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=channel_01 pri=0 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1760)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

---

this is my code:

```
@JavaProxy('org.nativescript.nstestandroid.ForegroundService')
class ForegroundService extends android.app.Service {
    onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId) {
        console.log('onStartCommand');
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return android.app.Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    onCreate() {
        console.log('onCreate')
        super.onCreate();
        this.startForeground(1, this.getNotification());
    }



 private getNotification() {
        const channel = new android.app.NotificationChannel(
            'channel_01',
            'ForegroundService Channel', 
            android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );
       // <const notificationManager = this.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as android.app.NotificationManager;
        //notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        const builder = new android.app.Notification.Builder(this.getApplicationContext(), 'channel_01');

        return builder.build();
    }
```

Comment: whats the version of your phone?

Comment: Why don't you simply use {N} local notifications plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to create `NotificationChannel` before posting into it new `Notification`. Smth like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
    String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
    int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
    channel.setDescription(description);

    // Don't see these lines in your code...
    NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

you are only creating new channel (as object), but never call `createNotificationChannel`

you probably have created notification channel on emulator, but not on device. there is also a chance that some devices with earlier OS versions may auto-create "default" notification channel for compatibility purposes, but newer OS versions may require channel creation before showing notification

some guide in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: God Bless you! it worked exactly as you described it! Thank you very much and have a great day!

Answer (score 3):

1. Create Application Class Like this

   ```
   public class App extends Application {

   public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();
       createNotificationChannel();
   }

   private void createNotificationChannel() {
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
           NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "Example Service Channel",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
           NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
           notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);

       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Create notification in your service class and call startForeground

```
Intent notificationIntent =  new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent, 0);        
Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText(userInput)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    
    
        startForeground(1,notification);
```

3. **Very Important** -> Done forget to mention your application class **App** in manifest file as -> **android:name=".App"**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.androidservicestemplate">
    
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" /> 
    <application
            android:name=".App"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
            <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the direct answer of the question. But if you getting the same error, solution could be checking the if the CHANNEL_ID defined in

```
NoficationCompat.Builder(this,CHANNEL_ID)
```

has same value with channel defined in createNoficationChannel() function

```
NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,channelName,Importance)
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34901930)